# Problems with paths in views after changing routes.rb to include nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two parent/child classes, Band and album. Band has many albums. After I found out i should use nested resources to help creating tables in the views, I got an error. In the views/albums/_form.html.haml when creating a new album the first line creates an error:

> "undefined method `albums_path' for
> #<#Class:0x00005578681058c0:0x00005578687128d0>"

The highlighted line:

```
= form_for @album do |f|
```

I think the problem is with @album something to do with it not being nested. I tried to use @band.album but it didnt work (i am very new to ruby on rails). My goal is to make a table where it outputs the albums of a specific band selected by the user.
Can you help please? My project is here: https://github.com/sebascorreia/ruby-coursework

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to update that for it to work because if it has become nested the path is now different.  If you need to see what it is run `rake routes`  All those old routes will change so you will likely see this for a bit unless you just  do a directory search for those route paths and then change them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a nested route with band.
You can try this.
Good luck and see you soon

app/views/albums/_form.html.haml

```rb
form_for [@band, @album] do |f|
```

app/controllers/albums_controller.rb

```rb
before_action :find_band

def new
@album = Album.new
end

private
def find_band
@band = Band.find(params[:band_id])
end
```

Your path to show

```rb
band_album_path(@band, @album)
```

Comment: Any idea how to do the same thing with a grandchild class? As in song belongs to album belongs to Band.